# Как сделать первую букву заглавной при подстановке строки в str.format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу генератор title'ов для сайта.
Хочу иметь несколько вариантов шаблонов и выбирать из них случайным образом, обрабатывая через str.format

Вопрос: можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при подстановке в шаблон первая буква слова становилась заглавной? (через определение формата)

Например, есть 2 шаблона:

- "Купить {} {} в интернет-магазине"
- "Лучшее предложение года! {} {} в интернет-магазине MyShop"

В строку первым аргументом подставляю тип товара, вторым - наименование.

- "Купить ноутбук Asus в интернет-магазине" - все ок
- "Лучшее предложение года! ноутбук Asus в интернет-магазине MyShop" - а вот тут не плохо было бы иметь заглавную букву для "ноутбука".

Answer (score 4):

> можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при подстановке в шаблон первая буква слова становилась заглавной?  (через определение формата)

Можно, если определить [`__format__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) для соответствующих элементов, чтобы `.title()` (или `.capitalize()`) неявно вызывались когда необходимо. Но проще явно вызвать:

```
>>> s = 'aBc def'; print('{t}'.format(s=s, t=s.title()))
Abc Def
```

`{s}` используется в форматах, где нужна строка как есть. `{t}` используется для `s.title()` версии.

Альтернативно, можно элементы, у которых `title` атрибут установлен, использовать: `'{s.title}'`:

```
>>> class Item:
...     def __init__(self, s):
...        self.s = s
...     @property
...     def title(self):
...         return self.s.title()
... 
>>> x = Item('aBc def')
>>> print('{x.title}'.format(**vars()))
Abc Def
```

Если на входе просто строки, то нельзя т.к. `str.format()` не разрешает произвольные выражения использовать в формате. В Питоне 3.6 появились: `f''` строки, которые разрешают произвольные выражения в формате:

```
>>> s = 'aBc def'; print(f'{s.title()}')
Abc Def
```

Ситуация схожа, когда при переводе (локализации) необходимо разные форматы использовать, то есть имеет смысл посмотреть на соответствующие библиотеки, как они с разными форматами работают.